# Clearscript V8 in ASP.NET 5 - v8-x64.dll could not be opened -- PE image doesn't contain managed metadata

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, v8, clearscript

I have issues with ClearScript. When I use them from regular project (class library or wpf), when dependency is added through nuget, also a post build script is added that copies `ClearScriptV8-32.dll`, `ClearScriptV8-64.dll`, `v8-ia32.dll` and `v8-x64.dll` to `bin` directory and everything works well. But when I try to use this library with new ASP.NET, things go wrong.

Nuget ClearScript package for dnx is downloaded to

```
C:\Users\lukasz\.dnx\packages\ClearScript.V8\5.4.3\lib\net40
```

I mean, `ClearScript.dll` is there but those 4 other files are not (they are `..\..\tools\native\{x86,amd64}\*`, just like in case of desktop app), and when I run app it says

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Cannot find file 'C:\Users\lukasz\.dnx\packages\ClearScript.V8\5.4.3\lib\net40\ClearScriptV8-32.dll'
```

So following my experiences from regular projects, I just copied those 4 files from

```
.dnx\packages\ClearScript.V8\5.4.3\tools\native\{x86,amd64}\*
```

to

```
.dnx\packages\ClearScript.V8\5.4.3\lib\net40
```

And then I get this error

```
Error: error CS0009: Metadata file 'C:\Users\lukasz\.dnx\packages\ClearScript.V8\5.4.3\lib\net40\v8-x64.dll' could not be opened -- PE image doesn't contain managed metadata.
error CS0009: Metadata file 'C:\Users\lukasz\.dnx\packages\ClearScript.V8\5.4.3\lib\net40\v8-ia32.dll' could not be opened -- PE image doesn't contain managed metadata.
```

I would asume that those dlls are somehow not valid for web version, maybe I need to get those dlls in some different way?

I could reproduce the issue creating new ASP.NET 5 project from WebApi template. I use single framework `dnx46`, no `core` as the projects I use are not compiled against it anyway. I use `ClearScript.V8 5.4.3`. DNX SDK version is `1.0.0-rc1-update1`.

I am simply creating

```
var engine = new V8ScriptEngine();
```

in the controller method.

Comment: Can you try moving those files (ClearScriptV8-\*.dll, v8-\*.dll) to your application's root directory?

Comment: What do you mean root directory? Where the code is? You mean solution or the project?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the root directory where your application is deployed. On your development machine that's probably the project root. From ClearScript's ReadMe: *For ASP.NET projects, we recommend that you add these assemblies as content files at the root of your web application and set their "Copy to Output Directory" properties to "Do not copy".*

Comment: I tried solution directory, solution/artifacts/bin/appname/, solution/artifacts/obj/appname/Debug, solution/appname/src/, solution/appname/src/wwwroot/ I also tried ~/.dnx/bin/, ~/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1/bin/ (and all other runtimes). Both IDE and Kestrel say that file is not found in same path as in my question.

Comment: I went into solution explorer to references/dnx 4.6/clearscript.v8 and I noticed it has all 5 dls in there. I tried upgrading to 5.4.5 and that has only 1 dll in the tree, program runs no problem, throws exception when I try to access page, but it expects dll in ~/.dnx/runtimes\dnx...\bin dir, when I copied them there it all works. I will try to update clearscript in my main project and see if it works.

Comment: Well, it works now, damn... So it was just the version.